# Add custom entity type for custom field in Shopware 6

Tags: php, shopware

In Shopware 6.4.0.0 it is possible to add custom fields which are based on Entities.

The list of entity types is limited:

[image: New custom field dialog]

Is it easily possible to add additional entity types, such as a list of available product properties?

*EDIT* https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-settings-custom-field/component/sw-custom-field-type-entity/index.js#L9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to add something like

```
            {
                label: "Product Property Group",
                value: 'property_group'
            }
```

to the select

https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-settings-custom-field/component/sw-custom-field-type-entity/index.js#L9

Then it is possible to create a custom field that lets us chose product properties.

Next we have to make this change persistent.

See https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/customizing-components

```
Component.override('sw-custom-field-type-entity', {
    computed: {
    entityTypes() {
        const types = this.$super('entityTypes');

        types.push(
            {
                label: 'Product Property Group',
                value: 'property_group'
            }
        );

        return types;
    }
    }
});
```